# OOP - ¿Como puedo acceder a un método no estático dentro de otra clase?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy creando una aventura de texto en Java, especialmente para entender mejor mi OOP, pero ahora mismo tengo problemas para implementar un método para obtener el cuarto en el que el jugador se encuentra actualmente.

Player:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private char gender;
    private Map<String, List<String>> inventory = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Character, Integer> position = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Player() {
        this("Gah", 'o');
    }

    public Player(String name, char gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.inventory.put("albums", new ArrayList<String>());
        this.inventory.put("instruments", new ArrayList<String>());
        this.position.put('n', 0);
        this.position.put('e', 0);
        this.position.put('s', 0);
        this.position.put('w', 0);
    }

    public void updateNorth(char direction) {
        if (position.get('s') > 0) {
            position.put('s', position.get('s') - 1);
        }
        else {
            position.put('n', position.get('n') + 1);
        }
    }

    public void updateSouth(char direction) {
        if (position.get('n') > 0) {
            position.put('n', position.get('n') - 1);
        }
        else {
            position.put('s', position.get('s') + 1);
        }
    }

    public void updateEast(char direction) {
        if (position.get('w') > 0) {
            position.put('w', position.get('w') - 1);
        }
        else {
            position.put('e', position.get('e') + 1);
        }
    }

    public void updateWest(char direction) {
        if (position.get('e') > 0) {
            position.put('e', position.get('e') - 1);
        }
        else {
            position.put('w', position.get('w') + 1);
        }
    }

    public void move(char direction) {
        switch(direction) {
            case 'n':
                updateNorth(direction);
                break;
            case 'e':
                updateEast(direction);
                break;
            case 's':
                updateSouth(direction);
                break;
            case 'w':
                updateWest(direction);
                break;
        }
    }

    public String getPositionToString() {

        String positionStr = "";

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> coordinate : this.position.entrySet()) {
            positionStr += coordinate.getValue() + " ";
        }

        return positionStr.trim();

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public Map<Character, Integer> getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Room:

```
public class Room {

    private String name;
    private Map<Character, Integer> location = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public Room(String name, int[] coordinates, List<Item> items) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location.put('n', coordinates[0]);
        this.location.put('e', coordinates[1]);
        this.location.put('s', coordinates[2]);
        this.location.put('w', coordinates[3]);
        this.items.addAll(items);
    }

    public String getLocationToString() {

        String locationStr = "";

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : location.entrySet()) {
            locationStr += entry.getValue() + " ";
        }

        return locationStr.trim();

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<Character, Integer> getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

GameMap:

```
public class GameMap {

    private Map<String, Room> rooms = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public GameMap(Room[] rooms) {
        for (Room room : rooms) {
            this.rooms.put(room.getLocationToString(), room);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

Lo que he pensado que sería más efectivo es iterar en los cuartos de la clase GameMap y cuando el valor de getPositionToString sea igual al cuarto, ese será el cuarto actual. Pero no se como hacerlo un método porque no puedo acceder to non-static methods sin haberlos instanciado.

Comment: cuantas instancias de `GameMap` piensas crear? Al parecer deberia ser solo una, si es asi, podrias implementar un patron *Singleton* para `GameMap` y si en `Player` necesitas iterar los `Room`, simplemente obtienes la instancia unica

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Klaimmore.

He escuchado sobre ese patrón, pero hasta ahora no conozco nada sobre design patterns, y de hecho quiero comenzar a leer un libro al respecto.

En efecto, será solo una instancia de GameMap. ¿Quieres decir que puedo crear en Player un método que se refiera a la instancia de GameMap?

Por ejemplo, ¿creo un objeto llamado gameMap con los rooms y así podría iterar con el metodo getRooms?

Comment: Exacto, si un Player necesita conocer del GameMap algo relativo a este, debe obtener una instancia de este, nunca crearlo. Posiblemente el GameMap se haya creado mucho antes.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Eso es lo que pensaba hacer, pero creía que era considerado mala práctica.